# the result when deep learning code is trained

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm newbe about deep learning. I'm starting project that requires deep learning about korean character recognition. The question is that when I run the deep learning code and training that, deep learning code is trained? If so, when I copy the code that is trained, I'll get two trained code??

Comment: I suspect you need to learn some basic concepts about deep learning first, but the answer to your question is generally yes - it's possible to copy the files of a trained network (if that's your intent, i'm not sure)

Comment: Thank you for comment. I just wonder that code is trained

Comment: It's not the "code" that is trained, it's the network (or more accurately - the weights and biases). If you don't know what that means, read the basics of machine learning first

Comment: A starting point for your research could be [here](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/). It's free and a straightforward bottom-up approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. With your code, you create the model
2. Then you have to train this model on some data
3. (Pre-)trained model can be copied and used on another device/whatever

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the code helps you to create the model and training is done on the data. When you actually copy the code, your copying the code only and not the variables it has learnt, so yes, when you copy the code you get a copy of the code and not the weights and biases data.